# Nexus 5 not recognized by adb anymore

Tags: android, adb, nexus-5

My Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.4) is suddenly not recognized by adb anymore. I know it's not the computer, because i have the same problem at work and at home and both computers do recognize other phones. When i plug in the phone, it shows that it is charging, but not the debug icon. I restarted the phone multiple times, turned the developer settings and the usb debugging on and off. Nothing seems to work.

Has anyone else ever had this problem? Any idea how to fix it? Could it just be the connector that is broken?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: What's the USB mode? (Settings -> Storage -> Overflowmenu -> USB computer conntection)
I have to set it on Camera (PTP)

Comment: It's set on "Media device", but I've tried "Camera" as well.

Comment: Setting to Camera worked for me on Nexus 7 after upgrade to 4.4.

Comment: Same problem, Have you found any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: No I have not. I'm still using the same phone, but was never able to debug on it again. I think it is a hardware issue, since other phones work fine with the same computer.

Comment: Same problem from now on with my n5 as well. Never happened in 4 years. Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805305/nexus-5-not-showing-on-connected-devices?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the right drivers from android sdk over [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) download the driver for bootloader.

Comment: I never had to install a special driver on the Mac. And as I said, other phones work fine. This one did as well until it just stopped - on two different computers at the same time, without any software updates...