# Nexus 5 not showing on connected devices

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, nexus-5

Up until recently I had no problems debugging with my Nexus 5 connected via USB cable to my PC (Windows 10).

 Suddenly I cant see my device in the "Connected Devices" list. can anyone help?

[Can't see nexus 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGOsB.png)

[Driver is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sNlp.png)

And I can edit my files through the explorer.
Help?

Comment: Connect and disconnect the phone. Switch off the debugging on device and switch on again. Restart Android studio. Sometime these things work. It happens to me now and then. Although it might be because I am using Android Studio preview version from Canary Channel. But they are worth trying

Comment: Your *Device Manager* window screenshot only shows `MTP` interface of your device but no `ADB Interface`. So you can't be sure that the *driver is OK*

Comment: different usb port maybe??!!

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I have already did all of these

Comment: @SaeedEntezari I have tried them all

Comment: @AlexP. How can I make sure?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Today I noticed the same behavior on my LG Nexus 5 with Android M. 
I also remember two icons that are in status bar when you were connected through USB. One for charging and one for debugging. None of these is showing anymore. 
My only guess is that some hardware is damaged. Probably the USB connection port. Yesterday I remember that my cable was causing unstable connection and the 2 icons I mentioned were appearing/disappearing repeatedly in one second(flickering). It looks like it was bad connected due to broken cable until finally it burned some internals.

I've seen other people complaining for the same reason. Nobody has discovered or posted any reasonable answer yet.

After years of programming apps and using n5 for debugging, this is for sure not driver (I'm on Mac OS X), adb, or other typical problem.

The only thing is left to try is restoring to factory.

**UPDATE:**

Before posting this answer I tried everything, changed a lot of cables, even tried booting into safe mode. And just after posting this answer here, I tried one more time to reconnect all cables from my MacBook and the charging icon appeared again!

My new guess is: there might be some bug probably related to battery. 
When started noticing the problem first my phone battery was about 11%. Now that it works again it's on 50%+.

And I say it's a bug because I know for sure that I ran a lot of apps from Android Studio with phone being below 50%.

Answer (score 0):

try to use  original nexus cable when connect from device to computer , i have this case and solve it when use this cable